# Why does Latin not have an instrumental case?

Tags: declension

Seeing so many similarities in grammatical structure between Sanskrit and Latin, why is it that Latin does not have an [instrumental case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_case) as Sanskrit does?

Comment: Sanskrit also has a dual (in addition to singular and plural) and a locative that Latin doesn't (really) have, and Greek doesn't even have an ablative.  I would guess that it's just another example of syntaxes simplifying, and the meanings of more specialized cases got lumped together with other cases.

Comment: Side note: if you Google "PIE cases", you might not get what you expect.

Comment: @MarJohnson: Bookcases with lots of volumes by Pokorny, I presume?

Comment: @Cerberus Wouldn't that be fun?

Comment: @MarJohnson isn't there a locative species of the dative in classical latin which periodically declines slightly differently (e.g. in the word locus)?

Comment: @virmaior Sure, and that's why I hedged with 'really', but at least in my (limited) experience, those few words are just considered historical oddities.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure there is more of a "why" to it than the fact that, in Latin, the ablative mostly absorbed the Proto-Indo-European instrumental's functions as the latter disappeared, just as the Greek dative did (which also happened to absorb some functions of the Proto-Indo-European ablative as it disappeared in Greek). Some other functions of the ablative were absorbed by the genitive in Greek. The Latin subjunctive also absorbed functions of the Proto-Indo-European optative, etc.