# When did Latin lose the locative?

Tags: language-evolution, declension, locative

Latin has, depending on who you ask, 6 or 7 cases. The 7th case is the locative – the Cambridge Latin Course (which I study) does not have it, rather it just lists words like 'domi' as 'at home' – not 'domus' as 'little house'. So my question is when, and how did Latin lose the locative case?

Comment: Strongly related: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/280/ablative-case-and-its-counterparts.

Comment: I didn't notice that - should I delete this question?

Comment: If you think this is already answered well enough. It's up to you.

Comment: It's related, but not the same question. Personally, I'd like a focus on the "why", not "when".

Answer (score 1):

As Latin aged and developed, from Old Latin to Classical Latin, combined with a change in sounds of Latin lead to the dropping of the locative. However, examples of it do still remain, such as "domi" - "at home", and "Romae" - "At Rome".

Comment: This is essentially a summary of what is written [here](http://latin.stackexchange.com/a/285/66). If this answers your question, we should close this question as duplicate after all. The point of closing a question is that all answers are collected in one place and answers *don't* have to be copied over...